# Theoretical link between Two Solutions and the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to Differential Equations, and am one step away from the solution to what was a very challenging exercise. Any help would be amazing.

Find two different solutions to the initial value problem

$$xy'-2x^2 \sqrt{|y|}=4y~,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~y(1)=0$$
and explain how the existence of two different solutions to this problem abides by the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

After a lot of work I found the solutions to this problem, namely
$|y|^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^2\ln|x|$, which renders two $x$ solutions for each $y$. However, I am not sure how to link this back theoretically to the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

I have two theories, but I am not sure regarding either of them:

${}$

$1.~$ the derivative of $xy'-2x^2 \sqrt{|y|}=4y$, that is to say $y'=2x \sqrt{|y|}+4\frac{y}{x}$, is $~\frac{xy}{|y|\sqrt{|y|}}+\frac{4}{x}$, and this is not defined at (1,0).

I am not sure if that is a valid way of justifying why the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem does not apply.

${}$

$2.~$ To show that there is no $L$, such that $f(x,y)-f(x,0) \leq L(y-0)$.

This leads me to $2x \sqrt{|y|}+4\frac{y}{x}\leq L(y)$.

Again, I am not sure if this is valid, and - if so - how to take it to the next step.

Any insight would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you!

${}$

PS:

[image]

Comment: Can you please state the "existence and uniqueness theorem"?

Comment: @giuseppeNegro
It's the Picard Lindelöf Theorem… I have added a picture, so that you can have a look...

Answer (score 3):

Setting $y=u^2$ for $y>0$ one gets 
$$
2xuu'-2x^2u=4u^2\implies xu'-2u=x^2\implies u=x^2(C+\ln x)
$$
For $y<0$ with $y=-u^2$, the same treatment gives
$$
-2xuu'-2x^2u=-4u^2\implies xu'-2u=-x^2\implies u=x^2(C-\ln x)
$$
In total, this gives 
$$
y(x)=\pm x^4(\ln(x))^2
$$
as solutions for $x>1$.
Also, the constant solution $y=0$ is a solution. You can construct further solution as piecewise functions
$$
y(x)=\pm x^4\max(0,\ln(x)-\ln(x_0))^2
$$
for any $x_0>1$, so that $y(x)=0$ for $x<x_0$.

---

And yes, the unboundedness of the $y$-derivative resp. the non-existence of a Lipschitz constant around $y=0$ demonstrates why the Picard-Lindelöf theorem does not apply. However, note that such an unboundedness does not imply the existence of multiple solutions, for instance $y'=1+\sqrt{|y|}$ has unique solutions.

Comment: Wonderful, LutzL! Thank you so much. So my reasoning under 1) is valid? My doubt is simply that the theorem talks about unboundedness, whereas I am proving that the y-derivative is /undefined/ at the given point. I just want to make sure I got this right...

Comment: No, undefined is not indicative of non-uniqueness. $|y|$ is not differentiable at $y=0$, but still globally Lipschitz.

Comment: So it is the /unboundedness/ of the y-derivative at y=0 that explains why the solution is not unique? Sorry to keep harping, but I just really want to get this...

Comment: The unboundedness makes the non-uniqueness possible, but it is not the only cause of it. You only have the hard fact that the boundedness of the $y$-derivative, resp. its continuity, implies uniqueness.

Comment: OK, but that means that in this specific situation, the unboundedness at (1,0) is a valid explanation of why it is possible to have two (or more) solutions, despite the theorem. Correct?